# Calculate residues at all isolated singularities of $f(z)=\frac{z^2+4}{(z+2)(z^2+1)^2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, singularity

> Calculate residues at all isolated singularities of $f(z)=\frac{z^2+4}{(z+2)(z^2+1)^2}$.

So I found the isolated singularities to be $z=-2$ and $z=i$.

Then I found the residue at $z=-2$.
$\operatorname{res}(f,i)=\lim_{z\to -2}$ $(z+2)\left(\frac{z^2+4}{(z+2)(z^2+1)^2}\right)$

$=\lim_{z\to -2} \frac{z^2+4}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{8}{25}$

but I don't know how to do the other one.
I tried this, since it's a double pole:
$\operatorname{res}(f,i)=\lim_{z\to i} \left((z-i)^2\frac{z^2+4}{(z+2)(z^2+1)^2}\right)'$,  but I got stuck because this didn't allow me to cancel the singularity. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\dfrac{z^2+4}{(z+2)(z+i)^2}$. Then $g(i)=\dfrac{-6+3i}{20}$ and $g'(i)=-\dfrac{8+31i}{50}$. So, near $i$ you have$$g(z)=\frac{-6+3i}{20}-\dfrac{8+31i}{50}(z-i)+\cdots$$and therefore$$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-i)^2}=\frac{-6+3i}{20}(z-i)^{-2}-\dfrac{8+31i}{50}(z-i)^{-1}+\cdots$$So$$\operatorname{res}(i,f(z))=-\dfrac{8+31i}{50}$$and the computation of $\operatorname{res}(-i,f(z))$ is similar.

Comment: Why did you declare a new function g(z)? Where did the original denominator of $(z+2)(z^2+1)^2$ go?

Comment: Note that\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{z^2+4}{(z+2)(z^2+1)^2}\\&=\frac{z^2+4}{(z+2)((z+i)(z-i))^2}\\&=\frac{z^2+4}{(z+2)(z+i)^2(z-i)^2}\end{align}and that therefore$$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-i)^2}.$$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! But then wouldn't g(z) include the $(z+2)$?

Comment: Yes! That was a typo. I have edited my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. Last question... how does $g(i)=\frac{-6+3i}{20}$? When I plug $i$ into g I get $\frac{3}{-4i-8}$.

Comment: Because\begin{align}\frac3{-4i-8}&=\frac{3(4i-8)}{(-4i-8)(4i-8)}\\&=\frac{-24+12i}{80}\\&=\frac{-6+3i}{20}.\end{align}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110948/discussion-between-complexanalysis-and-jose-carlos-santos).